# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}) if i use populate in server side code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

if i put populate in server side code i am getting error like this Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
if i remove the populate then code is working fine.
How can i solve this issue ?
My code is
ProductPage.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";
import { Container, Row, Col, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Input from "../components/UI/Input";
import { addProduct } from "../redux/actions";
import Modal from "../components/UI/Modal";
import "./Home.css";
import { generatePublicurl } from "../urlConfig";

function ProductsPage(props) {
  const category = useSelector((state) => state.category);
  const product = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [productDetailModail, setProductDetailModal] = useState(false);
  const [productDetails, setProductDetails] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [productPicture, setProductPicture] = useState([]);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("");
  const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState("");
  const handleClose = () => {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("name", name);
    form.append("description", description);
    form.append("price", price);
    form.append("quantity", quantity);
    form.append("category", categoryId);
    for (let pic of productPicture) {
      form.append("productPicture", pic);
    }

    dispatch(addProduct(form));

    setShow(false);
  };
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const createCategoryList = (categories, options = []) => {
    for (let category of categories) {
      options.push({ value: category._id, name: category.name });
      if (category.children.length > 0) {
        createCategoryList(category.children, options);
      }
    }
    console.log(options);
    return options;
  };

  const handleProductPicture = (e) => {
    setProductPicture([...productPicture, e.target.files[0]]);
  };

  const renderProducts = () => {
    return (
      <Table style={{ fontSize: 12 }} responsive="sm" className="mt-5">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {product.products.length > 0
            ? product.products.map((product) => (
                <tr
                  key={product._id}
                  onClick={() => showProductDetailsModal(product)}
                >
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>{product.name}</td>
                  <td>{product.price}</td>
                  <td>{product.quantity}</td>
                  <td>{product.category}</td>
                  <td>{product.createdBy}</td>
                </tr>
              ))
            : null}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  };

  const renderAddProductModal = () => {
    return (
      <Modal
        show={show}
        handleClose={handleClose}
        modalTitle={"Add New Product"}
        actionName={"Add Product"}
      >
        <Input
          label="Product Name"
          vale={name}
          placeholder="Product Name"
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Input
          label="Product Price"
          vale={price}
          placeholder="Product Price"
          onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Input
          label="Product Stock"
          vale={quantity}
          placeholder="Product Stock"
          onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Input
          label="Product Description"
          vale={description}
          placeholder="Product Description"
          onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        />
        <select
          value={categoryId}
          className="form-control"
          onChange={(e) => setCategoryId(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option>Select Category</option>
          {createCategoryList(category.categories).map((option) => (
            <option value={option.value} key={option.value}>
              {option.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        {productPicture.length > 0 &&
          productPicture.map((pic, index) => <div key={index}>{pic.name}</div>)}
        <input
          className="mt-3"
          type={"file"}
          name="productPicture"
          onChange={handleProductPicture}
        />
      </Modal>
    );
  };
  const handleCloseProductDetailModal = () => {
    setProductDetailModal(false);
  };

  const showProductDetailsModal = (product) => {
    setProductDetails(product);
    setProductDetailModal(true);
  };
  const renderProductDetailsModal = () => {
    if (!productDetails) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Modal
        size="lg"
        show={productDetailModail}
        handleClose={handleCloseProductDetailModal}
        modalTitle={"Product Details"}
        actionName={"Save Changes"}
      >
        <Row>
          <Col md="6">
            <label className="key">Product Name</label>
            <p className="value">{productDetails.name}</p>
          </Col>
          <Col md="6">
            <label className="key">Product Price</label>
            <p className="value">{productDetails.price}</p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col md="6">
            <label className="key">Product Quantity</label>
            <p className="value">{productDetails.quantity}</p>
          </Col>
          <Col md="6">
            <label className="key">Product Category</label>
            <p className="value">{productDetails.category}</p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <label className="key">Product Description</label>
            <p className="value">{productDetails.description}</p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <label className="key mb-3">Product Images</label>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {productDetails.productPictures.map((picture) => (
                <div className="productImageContainer ">
                  <img src={generatePublicurl(picture.img)} />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Modal>
    );
  };
  return (
    <Layout sidebar>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col md={12}>
            <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
              <h3>Products</h3>
              <button onClick={handleShow}>Add Product</button>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>{renderProducts()}</Col>
        </Row>
        {renderAddProductModal()}
        {renderProductDetailsModal()}
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default ProductsPage;
```

initialData.js

```
const Product = require("../../models/product");
const Category = require("../../models/category");

function createCategories(categories, parentId = null) {
  const categoryList = [];
  let category;
  if (parentId == null) {
    category = categories.filter((cat) => cat.parentId == undefined);
  } else {
    category = categories.filter((cat) => cat.parentId == parentId);
  }

  for (let cate of category) {
    categoryList.push({
      _id: cate._id,
      name: cate.name,
      slug: cate.slug,
      parentId: cate.parentId,
      children: createCategories(categories, cate._id),
    });
  }
  return categoryList;
}

exports.initialData = async (req, res) => {
  const categories = await Category.find({}).exec();
  const products = await Product.find({})
    .select(
      "_id name slug price quantity category createdBy description productPictures"
    )
    .populate({ path: "category", select: "_id name" })
    .exec();
  res.status(200).json({
    categories: createCategories(categories),
    products,
  });
};
```

For ref please find the attached image also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have to replace this {product.category} with {product.category.name}
populate is giving an object so i am getting this error after calling name is this object problem is resolved.

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
    import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";
    import { Container, Row, Col, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import Input from "../components/UI/Input";
    import { addProduct } from "../redux/actions";
    import Modal from "../components/UI/Modal";
    import "./Home.css";
    import { generatePublicurl } from "../urlConfig";
    
    function ProductsPage(props) {
      const category = useSelector((state) => state.category);
      const product = useSelector((state) => state.product);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
      const [productDetailModail, setProductDetailModal] = useState(false);
      const [productDetails, setProductDetails] = useState(null);
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [productPicture, setProductPicture] = useState([]);
      const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
      const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
      const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("");
      const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState("");
      const handleClose = () => {
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append("name", name);
        form.append("description", description);
        form.append("price", price);
        form.append("quantity", quantity);
        form.append("category", categoryId);
        for (let pic of productPicture) {
          form.append("productPicture", pic);
        }
    
        dispatch(addProduct(form));
    
        setShow(false);
      };
      const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    
      const createCategoryList = (categories, options = []) => {
        for (let category of categories) {
          options.push({ value: category._id, name: category.name });
          if (category.children.length > 0) {
            createCategoryList(category.children, options);
          }
        }
        console.log(options);
        return options;
      };
    
      const handleProductPicture = (e) => {
        setProductPicture([...productPicture, e.target.files[0]]);
      };
    
      const renderProducts = () => {
        return (
          <Table style={{ fontSize: 12 }} responsive="sm" className="mt-5">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Created By</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {product.products.length > 0
                ? product.products.map((product) => (
                    <tr
                      key={product._id}
                      onClick={() => showProductDetailsModal(product)}
                    >
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td>{product.name}</td>
                      <td>{product.price}</td>
                      <td>{product.quantity}</td>
                      <td>{product.category}</td>
                      <td>{product.createdBy}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))
                : null}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        );
      };
    
      const renderAddProductModal = () => {
        return (
          <Modal
            show={show}
            handleClose={handleClose}
            modalTitle={"Add New Product"}
            actionName={"Add Product"}
          >
            <Input
              label="Product Name"
              vale={name}
              placeholder="Product Name"
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              label="Product Price"
              vale={price}
              placeholder="Product Price"
              onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              label="Product Stock"
              vale={quantity}
              placeholder="Product Stock"
              onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              label="Product Description"
              vale={description}
              placeholder="Product Description"
              onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
            />
            <select
              value={categoryId}
              className="form-control"
              onChange={(e) => setCategoryId(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option>Select Category</option>
              {createCategoryList(category.categories).map((option) => (
                <option value={option.value} key={option.value}>
                  {option.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
            {productPicture.length > 0 &&
              productPicture.map((pic, index) => <div key={index}>{pic.name}</div>)}
            <input
              className="mt-3"
              type={"file"}
              name="productPicture"
              onChange={handleProductPicture}
            />
          </Modal>
        );
      };
      const handleCloseProductDetailModal = () => {
        setProductDetailModal(false);
      };
    
      const showProductDetailsModal = (product) => {
        setProductDetails(product);
        setProductDetailModal(true);
      };
      const renderProductDetailsModal = () => {
        if (!productDetails) {
          return null;
        }
        return (
          <Modal
            size="lg"
            show={productDetailModail}
            handleClose={handleCloseProductDetailModal}
            modalTitle={"Product Details"}
            actionName={"Save Changes"}
          >
            <Row>
              <Col md="6">
                <label className="key">Product Name</label>
                <p className="value">{productDetails.name}</p>
              </Col>
              <Col md="6">
                <label className="key">Product Price</label>
                <p className="value">{productDetails.price}</p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col md="6">
                <label className="key">Product Quantity</label>
                <p className="value">{productDetails.quantity}</p>
              </Col>
              <Col md="6">
                <label className="key">Product Category</label>
                <p className="value">{productDetails.category}</p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <label className="key">Product Description</label>
                <p className="value">{productDetails.description}</p>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <label className="key mb-3">Product Images</label>
                <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                  {productDetails.productPictures.map((picture) => (
                    <div className="productImageContainer ">
                      <img src={generatePublicurl(picture.img)} />
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Modal>
        );
      };
      return (
        <Layout sidebar>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col md={12}>
                <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                  <h3>Products</h3>
                  <button onClick={handleShow}>Add Product</button>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>{renderProducts()}</Col>
            </Row>
            {renderAddProductModal()}
            {renderProductDetailsModal()}
          </Container>
        </Layout>
      );
    }
    
    export default ProductsPage;
```